# "Technically," I'm not supposed to . .

Tags: english-to-german, idiom

We say in English, "Yes, but technically, I'm not supposed to." Or, "Technically speaking, the values should be higher..." This means there is an official take on things, but we will not be purist/perfect/exact/to-the-letter. How would you say this in German. Somehow *Technisch gesehen...* doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: I would use the term "technisch" when there are technical reasons for or against something (like in too heavy, small, ...), or when a certain method or technique should be applied or avoided (e.g. in sports, or handycraft, ...). But this is probably subject to interpretation and others may see and formulate it differently, yet be able to make themselves understood. More context might be helpful.

Comment: There are many ways to express different aspects of this but the Jack-of-all-trades would be "eigentlich". "Ich darf eigentlich nicht ..." "Eigentlich müsste der Wert höher sein" "Eigentlich kann da nichts passieren"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will man möglichst eng am Begriff "technically" bleiben, dann käme

> Nach den Regeln der Kunst würde man das Betriebssystem neu aufsetzen.

in Betracht, aber nicht "technisch gesprochen/gesehen". Geht es nur um offiziell/inoffiziell würde ich

> Formal bin ich nicht befugt Ihnen das Desinfektionsmittel zu überlassen.

oder eben

> Offiziell müssten die Werte höher sein, um den Notstand auszurufen.

sagen.

Offensichtlich wird "technically" aber im Englischen weithin ohne Assoziation zu Technik verwendet, so dass "eigentlich" als Übersetzung immer in Betracht gezogen werden muss:

> Eigentlich dürfte ich Dir das nicht sagen ...
>
> Eigentlich müssten die Werte höher sein.

Comment: Sorry but the first paragraph doesn't make any sense at all. The translation is unfitting. "Nach den Regeln der Kunst" is not what technically means - where did you get this translation from. Also I'd like to remind you to provide an English translation as the OP is in English.

Comment: "Technically" bedeutet doch technisch, oder nicht? Und Technik ist Handfertigkeit, Kunstfertigkeit - oder was denkst Du, was "technisch" ist?

Comment: "Nach den Regeln der Kunst" ist ein Spezialfall von "eigentlich müsste man", und zwar ein ziemlich enger Spezialfall. Als Antwort fände ich das zu eingeschränkt.

Comment: Regeln der Kunst/stand der Technik/Bewährtes Verfahren aka State of the Art/Best Practice is a very common situation. Technically may apply to that (and then it is fine to use). The answer mentions more alternatives for situations if this does not apply. In fact I think avoiding "technically" as it has unclear meaning would be best practice. ,)

Comment: This is good stuff. But it just shows how exact translations of idioms is nigh on impossible. A corollary is I hate speaking German with another American -- because typically they don't have a German mind behind it.

Comment: @toolforger: "Eigentlich müsste man ..." war aber nicht zu übersetzen sondern "technically". Als Nichtmuttersprachler bin ich mit "technically" nicht vertraut genug um zu sagen, wann genau es passt und wann nicht. Im Deutschen gibt es aber die Neigung bei "Technik" zuerst an "Elektrotechnik" zu denken ("das ist mir zu technisch"). "Mit welcher Technik hat van Gogh gemalt" oder "die Technik Müllers bei der Ballannahme" geht den Leuten dann aber doch flott über die Lippen bzw. ins Ohr.

Comment: This nicely illustrates that language and culture are interconnected! I might be going out on a limb here, but I think German doesn't have the perfect idiom for this because culturally the idea that something is "technically correct" but not actually the correct/relevant rule is simply not as common an occurrence as it is in the English speaking world.

Comment: @userunknown die exakteste Übersetzung von "Technically, I am not supposed to..." ist wirklich "Eigentlich sollte ich nicht...". Das deutsche "technisch" hat die Bedeutungsausweitung des englischen "technically" nicht mitgemacht und würde auf keinen Fall im Sinne von "technically, I am not supposed to" verwendet, das wäre für deutsche Muttersprachler absurd. (Als Anglizismus wandert es natürlich trotzdem ein.)

Comment: @toolforger: Ich wollte es nicht glauben, aber auch DeepL schlägt "eigentlich" vor, so dass ich es reumütig eingefügt habe.

Comment: @userunknown "Technically" bedeutet eben nicht nur "technisch" und gerade in diesem Zusammenhang hat es eine andere Bedeutung. Siehe z.B. [hier](https://www.lexico.com/definition/technically). Als Österreicher der lange genug in den USA gelebt hat, wäre mir diese Interpretation im gegebenen Kontext auch nie eingefallen.

Answer (score 46):

In short, I would use one of these

> normalerweise
>
> genau genommen
>
> streng genommen

Comment: As a native speaker, +1 to "genau genommen" for the case described by OP. "Eigentlich" might work as well but is a little different. Would be nice if the accepted answer went into that.

Comment: +1: "streng genommen" is what came to my mind immediately.

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I don't find "technisch" idiomatic. I'd use the modal particle "eigentlich" or an adverb such as "offiziell".

Comment: There's a difference between 'officially not allowed' and 'technically not allowed' though.

Comment: Certainly. However, the expressions I proposed seem to me to cover both examples.

Comment: @infinitezero is there, really? Elucidating that difference might be helpful in garnering an idiomatic phrase. OP notes that *technically* "means there is an **official** take on things"

Comment: @user151841 I wonder if OP miswrote that. I would interpret the difference in a more opposite manner: "We should technically do that, but we're officially doing this." In such a context, I would interpret that "technically" means it's established by norm, while "officially" means an authority is deciding it as so. Authorities can override normal courses of action.

Comment: @JoL The OP coalesces  two heterogeneous cases due to his mother language. In the first example, he means "officially", in the second "according to the standards".

Comment: "eigentlich" rings true in Swedish too

Answer (score 5):

If it's in a broader context than literally "technisch (gesehen)", "eigentlich" would be a good translation.

> Technically, I'm not supposed to do that, but I'll make an exception this one time.
>
> Eigentlich sollte ich das nicht tun, aber dieses eine Mal mache ich eine Ausnahme.

Answer (score 3):

You can say this in German. I'm not sure if usage came from a translation from English, but it's common to say it this way.

> Ja, aber technisch gesehen darf ich das nicht.

For example ( a bit contrived but I'm uncreative). Say there's a memo that you are to request permission before you print something.

> A: Hey, kannst Du die Seite für mich drucken? (*Hey, can you print that page for me?*)
>   B: Hmm, technisch gesehen müsste ich dafür um Erlaubnis fragen, aber bei unter 10 Seiten beschwert sich keiner. (*Well, technically I should request permission for this but typically nobody bats an eye if it's under 10 pages*)

Comment: I've never heard of this expression in the context you mention, but it might be one which is gaining some frequency.

Comment: That would support my impression that it is influenced by English.

Comment: Maybe. One day it might become conventionalized in German due to language contact in terms of calque.

Comment: Maybe it's a regional thing but "technisch gesehen" is used here just as commonly as "theoretisch gesehen" (in other words: quite frequently).

Comment: @ben What you currently use "theoretisch gesehen darf ich das nicht, aber ich tue es trotzdem"? Personally, I wouldn't.

Comment: @Nico yes, that's quite common here at my workplace. It could be because we have a mix of native german speakers and people with german as a secondary language but I would say I hear it on at least a weekly basis.

Comment: I second "theoretisch|offiziell|genau genommen|eigentlich darf ich das nicht, aber [praktisch] können wir das schon machen."

Comment: "Technisch gesehen" is pretty common and actually the first thing that came to my mind as well when I saw this question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think your examples could (perhaps should) rather be written as:

> "Yes, but **formally**, I'm not supposed to." or, "**Theoretically** speaking, the values should be higher.."

The difference being (in my opinion) that "technically" implies a somewhat **technical**, "real-world" context, as in:

- "technically I can't edit this PDF file" (i.e. I am unable to, due to file permissions - I may however, theoretically, know of a workaround to do so)
- "Yes, but technically, this window needs to stay closed" (i.e. while you could open the window, there is a reason - eg. a strong draft - as to why the window should stay closed)
- or, (following [this argument on quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-theoretically-and-technically-Which-one-is-the-antonym-of-practically)), while I **theoretically could** be able to perform a complicated piece of music (given enough time to practice) I still **technically can´t** (as I just haven't practiced enough).

whereas:

- "the value should be higher" implies a **theoretical** context (i.e. the existence of a *theoretical model* for these values)
- "I'm not supposed to" implies a **formal** set of rules you're supposed to conform to

Note how *to you*, all my examples above may only show a **formal** (or perhaps **theoretical**) valid use of the english language, but you may think they are **technically** not commonly in use! :-)

Secondly, I'd directly transfer these rules into German, and say (if I want to be *precise*):

- "Ja, aber **offiziell** darf ich das nicht"
- "**theoretisch** sollten die Werte höher liegen"

In a "real world" situation (see [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=technisch+gesehen%2Ctechnisch+betrachtet%2Cstreng+genommen%2Cnormalerweise%2Cgenau+genommen%2Ctheoretisch%2Ceigentlich&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ctechnisch%20gesehen%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btechnisch%20gesehen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTechnisch%20gesehen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctechnisch%20betrachtet%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btechnisch%20betrachtet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTechnisch%20betrachtet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cstreng%20genommen%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bstreng%20genommen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BStreng%20genommen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cnormalerweise%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnormalerweise%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNormalerweise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgenau%20genommen%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgenau%20genommen%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGenau%20genommen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctheoretisch%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btheoretisch%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTheoretisch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ceigentlich%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Beigentlich%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEigentlich%3B%2Cc0)), one would however use other words more commonly:

- *normalerweise*, *eigentlich*, *theoretisch*